# Debian - apt (not apt-get) autocompletion not working

Tags: debian, apt, autocomplete

I am on Debian Jessie 8.6. I noticed that `apt-get` gets the expected bash autocompletion when pressing tab for packages and command, but when trying to use it with `apt` it does not work. I remember using xubuntu 16.04 where it worked, so I find it strange that it does not work here. Is there a way to enable it for the command `apt` as well? If so, how?

Comment: Did anything work for you?

Comment: @Lynob I ended up moving to Ubuntu, so I can't help you, sorry.

Answer (score 41):

Debian does not come with 'bash-completion' installed and enabled.

If you're coming to Debian from, say, an Ubuntu background, where it is pre-installed and enabled by default, this can be a source of some confusion.

To enable/'fix' this, run (as root):

```
apt-get install bash-completion
```

Then, you have two options. You can either:

1. Enable it on a per-user basis for yourself, or

2. Enable it globally.

**1.**  If you want to enable it for just your user, edit `~/.bashrc` - add the following:

```
    if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
    fi
```

To try it without logging out and back in, run:

```
    . ~/.bashrc
```

Or open a new shell. Then try to use tab-completion with apt. That dot and space at the beginning (`.` ) is the same as using the `source` keyword in bash, but is more portable.

If you want it to work when `su`'d into the root account, do the same thing in root's home directory (typically `/root`).

**2.** To enable it globally, do the changes from (**1**) in the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead.

To anyone who's wondering why this works, the `.` in front of `/etc/bash_completion` does *not* refer to the current directory, since it has spaces around it. It instead makes the contents of the given file be evaluated in the currently running shell, instead of being executed in a new subshell. [It is standardized here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/dot.html)

In Bash, this `.` can be replaced by the command `source`, but this is not standardized by POSIX and is less portable so I tend to steer people away from using it. In this case, since it is specifically a program for extending bash, rather than something that needs to work in a bourne shell or `ksh`, you can feel free to substitute `source` for readability.

Incidentally, this behavior (not opening a sub-shell) is similar to the way DOS/Windows .BAT scripts work normally, changing the state of the shell they are run in. This is why if you `cd` into a different path in a shell script, you won't be in that path when the script exits like you would be in a .BAT.

Comment: I already did these steps, but that didn't help. Only works with apt-get, but apt doesn't.

Comment: @Andrea Oh, sorry, I didn't fully read your question, I guess. I'm not at my Debian box at the moment (in windows, all I've got is cygwin, unfortunately), but I'll try to figure it out from my debian machine when I'm back home.

Answer (score 5):

In Debian 9 Stretch just edit /etc/bash.bashrc and uncomment:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I have that uncommented as well, `apt` still gets no auto completion

Answer (score 3):

## How I solved it

I had auto completion problems trying to autocomplete `wget` with `apt-get install wg[TAB][TAB]` and I managed to solve it by removing the `--no-generate` parameter from the flies below:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-cache
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
```

It is worth mentioning that these files are available only after you install `bash-completion`.

The `--no-generate` parameter I'm referring to can be seen in the line below, but I removed ALL  `--no-generate`, not only from this line: 
https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/apt-get#L28

## How did I come to this point?

I got to this point after running `set -v` previous to `apt-get install wg[TAB][TAB]`, which showed that the command executed was:

```
apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames wg
```

and the output was an error:

```
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

When I executed `apt-cache pkgnames wg` without the `--no-generate` I correctly got the list for autocompletion:

```
root@484f5c8f56ba:/# apt-cache pkgnames wg
wgalician-minimos
wget2
wgaelic
wget
wgerman-medical
wget2-dev
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was _exactly_ what I needed. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most probably caused by

```
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` (typically in a file named `docker-clean`). In my case, it originated from Debian Docker image, see https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/799473bee3d388cf00bd55221b38a9d58bd6a2ba/scripts/debuerreotype-minimizing-config

Answer (score 2):

Copy this configuration file from Ubuntu: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt to the same directory in Jessie. You can also get the file here: http://pastebin.com/PRBMt3an

Comment: This is what I need. But auto completion is not working for apt, after I copied, renamed the downloaded apt file to the /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/. How to make it work?

Comment: The http://pastebin.com/PRBMt3an file was in Windows CR LF linefeed, this is why it did not work. I had to convert line format to Unix LF linefeed, so then worked after starting a new terminal.

Comment: Here is the 'apt' file with correct linefeed: http://www.filedropper.com/apt_1

Comment: This will work, but it's basically just implementing what I do in my answer. If you do it this way instead, know that you can use `dos2unix` to convert the line endings on files from pastebin (you might have to install it, though). You can also use this command, but to get the `^M` Carriage Return character you'll need to do `ctrl-v ctrl-m`; the 'carat-capital-M' won't actually work as is off the clipboard: `sed 's/^M$//' < file-to-fix > fixed-file`.

Comment: Line 161 says `autocleean`. Don't think that's how it is supposed to be spelled. That begs the question, is this file genuinely from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

## Applies to docker containers!

The content of your /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean file shows that it is configured to clean up package archives and caches after package installation and updates. However, the specific lines Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache ""; seem to be causing the issue with auto-completion.
To address this issue, you can modify the Dir::Cache::pkgcache and Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache directives to point to the correct cache directories. Here's an example:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin"; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin";
```

This modification sets the Dir::Cache::pkgcache and Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache to point to the standard cache directories used by APT.
After making this change, save the file and then run the following command to update the APT cache:

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score -1):

The alternative is to use a extension on top of apt. At least it is nicer and autocompletion works. On the double Tab. **Nala**.
[Nala apt frontend](https://linuxlifehacks.com/nala-beautiful-apt-frontend-for-ubuntu)