# Username autocomplete on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I've never had this problem before and after some research I'm a bit lost. I've got a few 1x.04 Ubuntu servers where if I type `sudo su [TAB]` then it lists a list of all available users to login to. However, this behaviour does not work in Ubuntu 20.04 for me anymore. I tried to follow several answers similar to this question (like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312456/debian-apt-not-apt-get-autocompletion-not-working)) but without any success...

Here's the end of my `~/.bashrc`

```sh
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

source /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

and `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC1091,SC2039,SC2166
# Check for interactive bash and that we haven't already been sourced.
if [ "x${BASH_VERSION-}" != x -a "x${PS1-}" != x -a "x${BASH_COMPLETION_VERSINFO-}" = x ]; then

    # Check for recent enough version of bash.
    if [ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -gt 4 ] || \
       [ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -eq 4 -a "${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}" -ge 1 ]; then
        [ -r "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion" ] && \
            . "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion"
        if shopt -q progcomp && [ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
            # Source completion code.
            . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
        fi
    fi

fi
```

I need to mention the the command autocomplete works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what makes sense to run sudo withsu, nor su with sudo? cant get that point

Comment: @djdomi How else do you want to login on users behalf from admin (not roots) console? `sudo` (as root) `su` (switch to user) **username**

Comment: `-U user, --other-user=user
                 Used in conjunction with the -l option to list the privi‐
                 leges for user instead of for the invoking user.  The secu‐`

Comment: in reference to the mab page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html did you dont know that sudo can ve run ad a different user?

Comment: @djdomi But that's not an answer to my questions... Anyway, I need to login on user's behalf because I need to perform more than one task and it's more convenient.

Comment: `sudo -u [TAB]` seems to work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `sudo su - [TAB]` works fine and as expected